# Custom Validation annotations not working properly using java 8 @Repeatable

Tags: java, java-8, bean-validation

Recently I added @Repeatable to my custom annotations. Once i added repeating annotaion to fields it was working fine , but fields with single annotoation is not working.

Example:

Following works:

```
@NotNull
@CustomValidator(type = Type.SIZE, max = 80)
@CustomValidator(type = Type.FIELD)
private String firstName;
```

But following does not works(Since it contains only one @CustomValidator):

```
@NotNull
@CustomValidator(type = Type.EMAIL)
private String email;
```

> CustomValidator.java

```
import java.lang.annotation.Repeatable;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;

@Constraint(validatedBy = CustomValidatorImpl.class)
@Repeatable(RepeatableCustomValidator.class)
public @interface CustomValidator {

    String message() default "";

    int min() default 1;

    int max() default Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    String format() default "dd.MM.yyyy";

    String[] values() default {};

    Type type();

    boolean optional() default false;

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

> RepeatableCustomValidator.java

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface RepeatableCustomValidator {
    CustomValidator[] value();
}
```

> CustomValidatorImpl.java

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class CustomValidatorImpl implements ConstraintValidator<CustomValidator, String> {
...............
@Override
public void initialize(CustomValidator constraintAnnotation) {
..........

}
    }
```

Dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

JAVA_VERSION="1.8.0_121"

Is there any thing that i am missing ?

Comment: Can you please add import statements so we can look which libraries you are using

Comment: @swayamraina done

Comment: I don’t know anything about the validation framework you’re using, but it seems your `CustomValidator` annotation lacks `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`. Generally, you should keep the annotations in sync, i.e. not only have the same retention policy, but also the same `@Target(ElementType.FIELD)` restriction.

Answer (score 1):

As @Holger also pointed out,

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
```

Adding these two to your `CustomValidator` class fixes the problem.
By the way, Normal validations should also not take place if we do not mention these two policies.
Are you sure it was working without these? As I tried, and it was not working.

Comment: YES. But after adding these two annotations , it is working for non-repeating annotations also.

Comment: `RepeatableCustomValidator` has an array which means it will accept 1 or of such types and hence non-repeating will also work.